# Scala mapreduce WordCount program

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce

I wrote this scala program for Word count. And the main class is given below

```
object aaa{
  def main(args:Array[String]) : Int = {
    val conf = new Configuration()
    val otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs
    if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
      println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>")
      return 2
    }
    val job = new Job(conf, "word count")
    job.setJarByClass(classOf[TokenizerMapper])
    job.setMapperClass(classOf[TokenizerMapper])
    job.setCombinerClass(classOf[IntSumReducer])
    job.setReducerClass(classOf[IntSumReducer])
    job.setOutputKeyClass(classOf[Text])
    job.setOutputValueClass(classOf[IntWritable])
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args(0)))
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path((args(1))))
    if (job.waitForCompletion(true)) 0 else 1
 }
}
```

Here I get a warning: 
"aaa has a main method with parameter type Array[String], but Hadooop.aaa will not be a runnable program. Reason: main method must have exact signature (Array[String])Unit" .

How to fix this? Also I cannot load this class in RunConfiguration. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: If the `main()` signature must be "(Array[String])Unit" then you can't return any values from it.  Remove your return values [0,1 and 2] and see what happens.

Comment: Removed and the warning fixed. But cannot load this class in RunConfiguration .

Comment: "But cannot load this class in RunConfiguratio" What happens when you try? Don't make us guess

Comment: In Run Configurations Main class is not listed while searching using the search button. If the full path is specified explicitly then "Error: Could not find or load main class aaa.scala".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably angry with your use of `: Int` where you declared main.

Try replacing your declaration of main with

```
def main(args:Array[String]) : Unit = {
    //...
}
```

And for each return with an exit code you made, replace those with a call to `System.exit(1)` or `System.exit(0)` as the case may be.

I'm sure you were looking for a more graceful termination, but that should do what you intended.